# Why does a vacuum environment almost always accompany thermionic emission?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons

I have not heard of the work function being pressure dependent. Is it because heat is dissipated too rapidly outside a vacuum and the electrons would interact with teh surrounding gas?

Comment: If you want the thermionic emission to make electrons for you to use for something, you then need to direct and manipulate the electrons, not have them scatter and dissipate in atmosphere.

Comment: So the physics is just the same at room temperature The electrons would be emitted but scattered and absorbed in the atmosphere.

Comment: Or back into the material. Yup.